# Ember.js | dynamically add option to an Ember.select

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember `select`:

```
{{ view Ember.Select valueBinding="category" contentBinding="categoriesList" }}
```

When I set the categoriesList in the controller in the init function, it works.

```
this.categoriesList = ['cat1', 'cat2'];
```

This populate my select as intended. But when I change this array after an ajax request, it stops working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For bindings to work you should use ember.js [built-in array methods](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_pushObjects) like `pushObject`, `pushObjects` or `removeObject` etc.

So to make things work try this:

```
this.categoriesList.pushObjects(['cat1', 'cat2']);
```

Hope it helps.